# wav audio not playing from a jar file created from intellij

Tags: java, audio, intellij-idea, wav

This is the piece of the code that I used. I tried to access the file from the folder called sound which is inside my project. I also marked the project as root resource folder.

URL url = this.getClass().getResource("./sound/ac.wav");

```
File file = new File(url.toURI());

WavFile wavFile = WavFile.openWavFile(file);

AudioInputStream stream1 = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
```

Comment: I can't see in provided code that `AudioPlayer` start playing the audio stream?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple code to play sound file.

```
private void playSound() {
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/test1/bark.wav");
        AudioStream audioStream = new AudioStream(inputStream);
        AudioPlayer.player.start(audioStream);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      // handle exception
    }
}
```